# Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.Loader' for adding application parts into MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to load application parts into an ASP.NET Core 2.0 MVC appication by using the `System.Runtime.Loader` package but it won't let me.

The error message says:

> FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.Loader, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

In the `Startup.cs` I use it like this (it should just be proof of concept that this works so I can move it into a dedicated class or an extension):

```
services
    .AddMvc()
    .ConfigureApplicationPartManager(apm =>
    {
        var parts = Directory.GetFiles(_rootPath, "*.Part.*");
        foreach (var part in parts)
        {
            apm.ApplicationParts.Add(new AssemblyPart(AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyPath(part)));
        }
    });
```

The package I installed has the version `4.3.0` and I'm using it in an ASP.NET Core 2.0 with .NET 4.6.2 project.

I thought maybe assembly-binding would help so I added a `runtime` configuration to the `app.config`

```xml
  <runtime>
    <gcServer enabled="true"/>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <publisherPolicy apply="no"/>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.Loader" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="en-US"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="4.3.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

but this didn't help. I also specified a range like `1.0.0.0-5.0.0.0` but this didn't work either.

The stack trace that IE ouputs is this:

> ```
> WebApiProject.Startup.<ConfigureServices>b__8_1(ApplicationPartManager apm)
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.MvcCoreMvcBuilderExtensions.ConfigureApplicationPartManager(IMvcBuilder builder, Action<ApplicationPartManager> setupAction)
>
> WebApiProject.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) in Startup.cs
> - 
> 38.        public IHostingEnvironment Environment { get; }
> 39.
> 40.        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
> 41.        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
> 42.        {
> 43.            // Add framework services.
> 44.            services
> 45.                .AddMvc()
> ...
> 50.                .ConfigureApplicationPartManager(apm =>
>
>
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.ConfigureServices(IServiceColection services)
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.EnsureApplicationServices()
>
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
> ```

In the output folder there are a lot of different `System.Runtime.*` files but none of them is named `System.Runtime.Loader`. Maybe this is the problem but where is this file? I searched the packages but there is no such `.dll` so why is VS trying to load it?

---

## Update

Oh, great. I found the package. NuGet did not install it as usual into the `packages` folder of the soulution but instead it was here:

```
c:\Users\%USER%\.nuget\packages\system.runtime.loader\4.3.0\lib\
```

Sadly there is no version `net462`. The folder contains an empty file named: `_`

There are couple of other folders but there is only one `.dll` there:

```
MonoAndroid10\
MonoTouch10\
net462\
netstandard1.5\ <-- System.Runtime.Loader.dll
xamarinios10\
xamarinmac20\
xamarintvos10\
xamarinwatchos10\
```

Why does this even install? How is it possible that I can use the types in code but the `*.dll` fails to load even if I copy it to the output folder? Is this even supposed to work in a project that mixes .net core and the *old* framework?

---

Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: This is too weird. I guess I'll stick to the old `Assembly.LoadFile` which by the way works just fine... the interesting part will probably begin as soon as I'll try to load other dependant assemblies but that's another story.

Answer (score 5):

See
https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/22142

The TLDR is that System.Runtime.Loader is not supported for .Net Framework

You will have to use Assembly.Load() instead